# Open Bluetooth file transfer wizard in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I have newly installed Windows 8 Pro in my laptop, I have hidden the Bluetooth tray icon from the notification bar:

[image]

And now, I am not able to find the Bluetooth file transfer Wizard anywhere,

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you most likely did was click on **Remove Icon** from the menu, not hide the icon:

[image: 1]

To bring the [image: 2] tray/notification area icon back:

1. At the Start Screen press <kbd>[image: 3]</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. Search for "bluetooth" and click on **Change Bluetooth settings**:

   [image: 4]
3. Select the **Show the Bluetooth icon in the notification area** option and OK your way out:

   [image: 5]

Answer (score 7):

Hit the Start key and type:

```
fsquirt
```

Run it, then touch Receive files and from the android device, share the media using bluetooth.

Comment: Bluetooth is maddeningly slow for copying files though...

Answer (score -1):

You do not need wizard transfer, just pair your device with your notebook and after that open
explorer in which you will see icon representing your device (phone or tablet). By clicking on this icon you will be able to browse whole content of device (photos for example), then you can copy it to your notebook ..