# Files from Android to Windows 8.1 pc

Tags: bluetooth, android, windows-8.1, transfer

i would like to transfer some pictures from android phone to my windows 8.1 laptop over a bluetooth, but even when i paired the devices i don't have on the bt icon in windows buttons to send or recieve file (there is only Add device, show devices, join network, open settings, remove icon), i don't know what to do, because when i choose in phone to send the files, it says error, computer rejected or something like that. Can anybody help me what should i do? Thank You. Frank.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows 7 or 8 or 8.1, run `fsquirt` - it gives the ability to send or receive files from a paired device.  I've used it to copy MP3 files to my Android phone, and they automatically show up in my Google Play Music app.

More details in this article on [plugable.com](http://plugable.com/2013/11/11/easy-way-to-use-bluetooth-to-exchange-files-with-your-phone-in-windows-fsquirt-guide)

Comment: man... I was searching for a way to do this for days.. Thanks! but why don't we have this option by default?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the icon to show in the status area using the instructions here: [Open Bluetooth file transfer wizard in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/540498/open-bluetooth-file-transfer-wizard-in-windows-8?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Go to desktop, find bluetooth icon in the system tray, right click it, and select "receive file". Then send the files from your android device. 
Same goes for sending files: You can send files from the desktop, I think modern UI does not support sending via bluetooth. I could be wrong though.

[image]

Comment: OP has explicitly stated that he doesn't have those context menu options.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows doesn't show the Bluetooth icon in systray (near the clock, check the upward arrowhead to make sure you can see all icons) and you know Bluetooth is on (probably, if you're able to start sending), it may be disabled in settings.

Run "Change bluetooth settings", not the fullscreen Metro app (called just "Bluetooth settings" on my 8.1), but the one that looks like a plain old windows dialog. There should be a checkbox for enabling the Bluetooth icon.

(Other/better instructions can probaby be found, but here's a screenshot. I also recommend looking at [Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) as a handy way to access files on Android devices. There is no need to use their services, the app alone works as a web server.)
[image: Bluetooth dialog screenshot]

Comment: Here's how to call this dialog window: `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL bthprops.cpl,,1`