# Can't send files from Android to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have a Windows 8.1 Computer, and an Android device (a Samsung galaxy fame to be precise).

I have managed to pair them both via bluetooth, however when I try to send a file, it fails for some reason.

This even happens when I use the file transfer wizard - The file transfer wizard just keeps waiting for files, and doesn't even recognise that a file has been sent.

Pictures are shown below.

Please could someone help me please?

Computer:
[image: Windows 8.1 computer]

Phone:
[image: Android Phone]

(Imgur album link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq29i.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files from Android to Windows 8.1 pc](http://superuser.com/questions/677223/files-from-android-to-windows-8-1-pc)

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you for the suggestion, but I have already seen that question. I do have a bluetooth icon on my system tray, and the transfer wizard does not help (as I stated in my question).

Answer (score -1):

fsquirt in the WIN 8.1 Start screen search fixed my issues with receiving files- Galaxy Note 4 is my phone.

bluetooth connect through pc devices on win8 or Bluetooth scan on Note4.  Pair the devices.
run fsquirt before you begin sending to the win8.1 and use it to send to phone if you want to. other ways to send to the note4

Comment: This is very hard to understand. I'm not sure what you're trying to explain here or if this is even an attempt to answer the question. Please edit your answer to clarify.

Comment: If the file transfer wizard is `fsquirt`, then I have tried that.